# Mount snap "hello": read-only file system

Tags: 18.04, snap

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04. Tried to run a `snap` of  an application and it failed with `read-only file system`. To make this as simple as possible, I then tried to install `hello` with the same result below:

```
$ sudo snap install hello
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Mount snap "hello" (20) (mkdir /snap/hello: read-only file system)
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. My bad. This is first install on SSD.
I followed the recommendation to change the */etc/fstab* and add the *noatime* flag. I miss-typed the flag and after the reboot the **/ filesystem** was mounted as *readonly*.
I decided to reboot and noticed a message at boot time indicating the **/ filesystem** was *readonly*. Corrected the flag, rebooted and was able to install the hello application successfully.